# How can I play/pause the animation in toggle class button?

Tags: animation, css-animations, togglebutton

I tried to play and pause the animation using the toggle class button. Could you please give some suggestions?

Using this code, When I click the play/pause button the animation does not pause.

```
In my HTML file I write something like this:

<button type="submit" id="btn">play/Pause</button>
```

In my  CSS file I write something like this:

```
.mysun, .mysky   {
  animation-play-state: paused;
  };
```

In my JS file I write something like this:

```
btn.onclick = myFunction;
function myFunction() {
  var sun = document.getElementById("sun");
  var sky = document.getElementById("sky");
  sun.classList.toggle("mysun");
  sky.classList.toggle("mysky");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

how about trying !important next to
sky.classList.toggle("mysky");?